# Geriebene Möhren zu essen(,) ist gesund

Tags: comma

Was ist korrekt?

1. Geriebene Möhren zu essen, ist gesund.
2. Geriebene Möhren zu essen ist gesund.

Comment: Beides:
https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201# ( §75)

Comment: [Please do not answer a question in a comment](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment).

Comment: Ich habe die Regel nicht gefunden, die meinem Fall der Zeichensetzung entspricht.

Comment: Mein Fall ist einzigartig – weswegen ich zögere, – weil das Infinitiv das Subjekt des Satzes ist.

Comment: Eben: Es gibt hier keine Regel, die ein Komma verlangt. Es ist daher optional (am Ende von §75). Tschuldigung dass ich das vergessen hab dazuzuschreiben.

Comment: @David Vogt: Ich konnte nicht anders: Das System sagte mir, die Mindest-Textlänge für eine Antwort sei nicht erreicht, auch als ich mehr hinzufügte; vielleicht ein technischer Fehler in dem Moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ein Komma wäre erforderlich, wenn die Infinitivgruppe mit "um zu", "anstatt zu" oder ein paar ähnlichen Gruppen eingeleitet würde.

> **Anstatt** geriebene Möhren zu essen, taue ich mir eine Pizza auf.

Ein Komma wäre erforderlich, wenn die Infinitivgruppe von einem Substantiv abhinge.

> Ich hege den **Wunsch**, geriebene Möhren zu essen.

Ein Komma wäre erforderlich, wenn die Infinitivgruppe von einem sog. Korrelatwort abhinge.

> **Es** ist gesund, geriebene Möhren zu essen.

In sonstigen Situationen *kann* man ein Komma setzen, *muss* aber nicht. Insofern sind beide Varianten in Ordnung.